# Multipass on windows host: adding networking options with VirtualBox gui?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-multipass

I'm playing around with Canonical's multipass running on a Windows (11 Home if that matters?) with VirtualBox as the driver/backend.

Trying to figure out how to go about adding another network interface for bridged networking.

Is there some good way to run the normal virtualbox gui for this?

When I try with PsExec, it just keeps showing modal popup warning:

"The virtual machine that you are changing has been started. Only certain settings can be changed while a machine is running. All other changes will be lost if you close this window now."